# Medium API to update a post / article

Tags: medium.com-publishing-api

I looked at the Medium API, but I could only find an API to create a post or article on Medium.

​`POST https://api.medium.com/v1/users/{{authorId}}/posts`

I want to update my existing post through an API, but I couldn't find one.

Is there an API for updating Medium post?

Here is the API documentation:

https://github.com/Medium/medium-api-docs

Comment: are you find response? I have same issue!